# Spherical Bessel functions

Tags: inequalities

I wish to show that

$|j_n(x)| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ and $x>0$, where $j_n$ is the spherical Bessel function of the first kind.

Experimenting with Matlab I am sure that this is the case by I am unable to prove it analytically.

Since

$j_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x)$,

where $J_n$ is the standard Bessel function of the first kind, it is sufficient to show that

$|J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x)| < \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$

for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ and $x>0$.

Comment: Since $J_{\nu}(x) = O(\nu^{-1/3})$, uniformly in $x$ and $\nu$, in principle this reduces your bound to a finite computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Abramowitz and Stegun, Handbook of Mathematical Functions, you will find the formula 10.1.52
$$\sum_0^\infty j_n^2(x)={Si(2x)\over 2x}.$$
Consequently
$$|j_n(x)|\le {1\over\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{{\max_{[0,\infty)}|Si(x)|\over 2}}\sim {0.962\over\sqrt{x}}.$$

Comment: That question is discussed in details in L.J. Landau, J. London Math. Soc. (2) 61 (2000) 197-215

A better bound exists, namely for all $\nu$ and $x$ in $(0,\infty)$,  
$$
|j_{\nu}(x)| < \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{c}{x^{5/6}}
$$
with 
$$
c=0.98479...<1
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the inequality for all $x$ and not just asymptotically, then it may be helpful to look at the phase portrait of the differential equation satisfied by the modulus function $M_\nu(x)$, where $J_\nu(x) = M_\nu(x) e^{i\theta_\nu(x)}$. The equation can be found in section [10.18](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.18) of the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/). If the phase trajectories never cross the submanifold $M_\nu(x)=\sqrt{2/\pi}$, you are in luck.